A couple of questions regarding differential drive 4W vs 2W and differential drive(DD) vs skeed steering(SS)
Hello fellow enthusiasts, I'm new to robotics. I have some confusion regarding the kinematics of 4W differential drive (4WDD) vs 2W differential drive (2WDD) and differential drive (DD) vs skid steering (SS) that I'd like to clear up. I'd like to grasp the concepts in the context of kinematic model. Let me list them here:

In case of 2WDD robot, two rear standard wheels of rubber tires and 1 front castor wheel, only the rear wheels are considered for kinematic model, so its 2WDD. Is a robot with two rear standard wheels and two front castor wheels considered 4W or 2W?

Let's say a differential drive robot with four standard wheels of rubber tires, wheels on each side have the same angular velocities i.e. wheels fl,bl have speed w1 and fr,br have w2 when turning. Can it be modelled kinematically as if it was a 2WDD robot i.e. can the wheels on each side be lumped together due to similar angular velocities? If so, is it a 4WDD or 2WDD robot?

Are differential drive & skid steering the same thing, is the kinematics of a 4WDD different than a SS? If they're different then what necessitated SS or what are the shortcomings of a 4WDD that SS had to be formulated?


That's quite a bunch!! TIA

One question per post, please.
